# Different kernels for different features - scikit-learn SVM

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to build a classifier using `sklearn.svm.SVC` but I would like to train the kernel separately on different subsets of features to better represent the feature space (as described [here](ftp://ftp.esat.kuleuven.be/stadius/adaemen/adaemenEMBC09.pdf)).

I have read the User Guide [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gp-kernels) and I understand that I can create kernels that are sums of individual kernels or feed into the SVC a precomputed kernel (`kernel = 'precomputed'`), but I do not understand how I apply different kernels to different features? Is there a way to implement this in `sklearn`?

I have found a way to calculate kernels in sklearn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gp-kernels), and so I could calculate the kernel on each set separately. However, once I output the distance matrix, I am not sure how I would use it to train the SVM.

Do I have to create a custom kernel like:

```
if feature == condition1:
   use kernel X
else:
   use kernel Y
```

and add it to the SVM?

Or is there any other python libraries I could be using for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the problem of `Multiple Kernel Learning (MKL)`. Where you can train different kernels for different groups of features. I have used this in a multi-modal case, where I wanted different kernels for image and text.

I am not sure if you actually can do it via scikit-learn.

There are some libraries provided on GitHub, for example, this one: https://github.com/IvanoLauriola/MKLpy[1](https://github.com/IvanoLauriola/MKLpy)

Hopefully, it can help you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple kernel learning is possible in `sklearn`. Just specify `kernel='precomputed'` and then pass the kernel matrix you want to use to `fit`.

Suppose your kernel matrix is the sum of two other kernel matrices. You can compute `K1` and `K2` however you like and use `SVC.fit(X=K1 + K2, y=y)`.

Comment: The problem with this implementation, as far as I understood it, is that you cannot learn the weights of each kernel whilst the package that @alift suggested allows you to do that

Comment: What do you mean by tuning the weights of a kernel? Are you thinking of a convex combination of `K1` and `K2`? Or the hyper-parameters of `K1` and `K2`, such as the length-scale parameter of a RBF or the polynomial degree?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to use some kind of combination of weak kernels rather than finding the optimal view for each of my feature sets. They explain the idea in the introduction to this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231215003653

Comment: This is all well and good, but none of these details are present in your Question. That makes it hard to write a useful answer.

Comment: These are thoughts I have had and in information I have come across since asking the question, also thanks to alift's answer above, which is why it is not in the original question. I can update the question now if you believe it would be more useful to other users